How to Enable Scrolling Beyond the Last Row in WPF DataGrid?
I am working on a WPF application and using a DataGrid to display data. I would like to enable scrolling beyond the last row of the DataGrid, similar to the "Scroll Beyond Last Line" feature in VSCode. This would allow users to scroll past the last row and have some empty space at the bottom of the DataGrid.
I have searched for solutions but haven't found a clear way to achieve this. Could someone please provide guidance or code examples on how to enable this functionality in WPF DataGrid?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I added margins to the ScrollContentPresenter in the DataGrid template, but it did not work.

Maybe you can add below the DataGrid a Grid with a minimal height.

Thank you for your response. It might be a simple task, but could you please guide me on how to add the grid?

You can detect the last row and set the bottom margin of this row to a value that meets your desired trailing empty space.
There are many solutions to accomplish this like using a MultiBinding.
Another simple solution is to register a DataGridRow.Loaded event handler:
MainWindow.xaml
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <EventSetter Event="Loaded"
                   Handler="DataGridRow_Loaded" />      
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
private const int TrailingEmptySpaceHeight = 200;

private void DataGridRow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (sender is not DataGridRow dataGridRow)
  {
    return;
  }

  var dataGrid = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(dataGridRow);
  int rowIndex = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(dataGridRow);
  bool isLast = rowIndex == dataGrid.Items.Count - 1;
  dataGridRow.Margin = isLast
    ? new Thickness(0, 0, 0, TrailingEmptySpaceHeight)
    : new Thickness(0);
}


Thank you for your code snippet! I tried it out, but unfortunately, the scrolling behavior was a bit unstable, with some vertical jitter. I’m still seeking a better solution. If you have any further guidance or alternative examples, I’d greatly appreciate it.

Have you disabled row virtualization? There shouldn't be any scrolling issues.

Virtualization is necessary.
